# Can one find $m$ vectors such that any subset of $n$ vectors is linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

While reading "proofs from the book" I stumbled upon a passage which the writers seem to find clear. I can prove it if I can prove the following reformulation:

Given $m>n$, there exists a choice of vectors $\{v_1, .., v_m\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that any subset of $n$ vectors $\{v_{i_1}, .., v_{i_n} \}$ is linearly independent.

I thought about some kind of determinant argument, or some sort of generalized Gram-Schmidt procedure, but I cannot quite figure it out.

Comment: If you choose the vectors uniformly at random from the unit sphere centered at the origin, with probability 1 they will satisfy your desired property.

Comment: Cool! How does one show this? :)

Comment: Consider first $n=2$.  Each new point needs to avoid the union of a bunch of lines, in the unit circle.  The total area of the lines is zero.  For $n>2$ the argument is similar, just harder to visualize.

Comment: Try this one $v_i = (1, i, i^2, \ldots, i^{n-1})^\top$, where $i \in \mathbb{N} $.

Comment: @echzhen why does that one work?

Comment: @M.Van because [Vandermonde matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).  Or equivalently: for any $n+1$ points in the $xy$ plane, there is a unique $n$th degree polynomial through those points.

Comment: I still do not see it, is there an argument without Vandermonde matrices which is more direct?

Comment: For example, is there an immediate way to see any choice of $n$ elements of the $v_i$ are linearly independent?

Answer (score 3):

Let $v_i = (1, i, i^2, \ldots, i^{n-1})^\top \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $i\in \mathbb{N}$. Take any subset $\{v_{i_1}, \ldots, v_{i_n}\}$, hence
 $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1& \ldots & 1 \\
  i_1 & i_2& \ldots & i_n \\
\vdots&\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\
  i^{n-1}_1 & i_2^{n-1}& \ldots & i^{n-1}_n
 \end{pmatrix},$$
is square Vandermonde matrices.
$$\det A = \prod\limits_{1\leq k < l \leq n} (i_l - i_k) \neq 0.$$